# Cluster analysis combined with random forest

Tags: cluster-analysis, random-forest

I have performed a cluster analysis on a dataset characterized by many features considering only two numerical features. In this way, I have identified a certain number of homogeneous classes. Then, I have fitted a random forest to the data, in which the dependent variable is the class identified with the cluster analysis, and the independent variables are the features not considered in the cluster analysis, which are numerical and categorical. The main scope of fitting the random forest is feature selection, since I would like to figure out which features impact the most on the prediction of the class. Do you think that this approach could be reasonable? Would you suggest another approach to feature selection? Thanks a lot in advance